# SSIS data conversion from CSV source column NULL to DB destination Decimal(18,2)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

First of all, when the column *isn't* NULL, it is successfully able to do the conversion. The destination DB field accepts null values.

In my **Data Conversion** step I have set the Input Column's DataType to `numeric[DT_Numeric]`, Precision 18, and Scale 2.

I have two rows in my CSV, the first row does not contain any NULLS.. and if I execute that it's a success. However when I add a 2nd row with a NULL value in that column it fails and I get these errors:

> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "Column 24" (138) to column "DbColumn24" (22).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>
> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[DbColumn24]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[DbColumn24]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I do not think I need a **Derived Column** step before data conversion step to handle any nulls because the DB column accepts nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your source is a CSV, I doubt that you actually have any NULL values in your source at all.  More likely you have empty string values, which are not the same as NULL, and empty strings cannot be implicitly converted to Decimal.   You will probably have to explicitly convert the empty strings to NULL in an expression.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. So it's actually string "NULL".

Comment: So when a CSV is generated NULL actually converts to an empty string rather than the actual word "NULL" right? I might need to modify my dummy csv "NULL"'s to empty strings then.

Comment: No, you can skip the empty string step.   If your CSV contains the string "NULL", then you just need to explicitly convert "NULL" (the string) to `NULL` (the DBNull value.)

Comment: Alright so this is it [Column 24] == "NULL" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [Column 24]. I then convert it to decimal in the data conversion step.  Thank you so much Tab Alleman!

Answer (score 1):

The work around would be
1) First convert the column to `varchar/nvarchar`
2) Use derived column to convert to `Decimal` 
3) Map the converted column to destination